# Cloning on ubuntu takes a long time

Tags: git, git-clone

I have installed Git in ubuntu using the command

```
sudo apt-get install git-core 
sudo apt-get install git
```

After this, I tried to install node.js using the command

```
git clone git://github.com/ry/node.git
```

At this step, it says

```
Cloning into node..
```

and takes a long time and does not return.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try 'git clone -v; , for verbose output.

Comment: It's a very large project, and you are cloning the whole thing.  It will take a while.

Comment: define "a long time".  And how fast is your internet connection?  Looks like you did everything fine.  You may just need to be more patient.  node is a big project.

Comment: How long is long? On my machine: `josef@linux:development$ time git clone git://github.com/ry/node.git
Cloning into node...
remote: Counting objects: 50773, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13657/13657), done.
remote: Total 50773 (delta 40039), reused 45916 (delta 36440)
Receiving objects: 100% (50773/50773), 39.54 MiB | 816 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (40039/40039), done.

real    1m33.404s
user    0m9.617s
sys     0m1.936s`

Comment: I waited for around an hour.. Is that time very less? How long do you think it will take :( My net connection is pretty decent at 2 Mbps

Comment: Yes, it took me a lot less time than one hour. 1 minute 33 seconds at 816 KiB/second. Post the output of the clone command with `-v` switch as instructed above in your question above.

Comment: the only verbose I get is **Cloning into Node** :( I use the command _time git clone -v git://github.com/ry/node.git_

Comment: How fast is the operation in KiB/sec? It's part of the output of the command. See my previous comment; my speed was 816 KiB/sec.

Comment: Hi Josef, it does not show any verbose output at all other than ** Cloning into Node**. I use the same command as given above. What could be the problem. It has been almost 2 hours and still there has been no other verbose :(

Comment: Can you clone any other git repos? And try posting the output of git --version and uname -a just for the sake of completeness. Have you installed git from the ubuntu repos or manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That repository (`git://github.com/ry/node.git`) actually redirect to `joyent` account.

Try the *destination* url, with git or https protocol and see if the clone is faster.

```
git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
```

Plus, 2 days ago, GitHub was experiencing some issue which could have affected the clone:

> 10:11 We are currently experiencing issues with one of our file servers. This affects a subset of repositories.
>   10:05 UTCWe are investigating issues with one of our file servers.

---

I just tested it with both protocols:

```
vonc@voncp1 ~/ $ time git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
[ VonC,vonc@laposte.net for github.com ]
Cloning into 'node'...
remote: Counting objects: 92208, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23478/23478), done.
remote: Total 92208 (delta 72604), reused 85936 (delta 67189)
Receiving objects: 100% (92208/92208), 57.96 MiB | 4.49 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (72604/72604), done.

real    0m34.156s
user    0m9.777s
sys 0m2.104s
```

and:

```
vonc@voncp1 ~/ $ time git clone https://github.com/joyent/node
[ VonC,vonc@laposte.net for github.com ]
Cloning into 'node'...
remote: Counting objects: 92208, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23478/23478), done.
remote: Total 92208 (delta 72604), reused 85936 (delta 67189)
Receiving objects: 100% (92208/92208), 57.96 MiB | 3.48 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (72604/72604), done.

real    0m43.459s
user    0m10.153s
sys 0m1.752s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot VonC. The https approach worked!

Comment: Huh, weird. `time` command works for everything but `git clone` for me :/

Comment: @Arin Strange: ask a new question with your OS and git version.

Comment: @VonC Actually, I tried `/usr/bin/time git clone ...` instead of `time git clone ...` and it worked for some reason.

Comment: @Arin OK, maybe an alias or a function `time()` was overriding the system `/usr/bin/time` executable.